# How to count people in a given area without using phone traffic data?

Tags: sensors, hardware, tracking-devices, positioning

**DESCRIPTION**: I am working on a project to find out how many people are in a given region. Basically I want to make a heatmap showing how people move in a specific day throughout 24h. In order to do so, I was able to get some phone traffic data that shows me people's traffic data (how much time they spend on a given area) and it works perfectly.

**PROBLEM**: phone traffic data is very expensive.

**QUESTION**: Are you aware of any technology that would allow me to count/estimate the number of people in a given region without using phone traffic data? Feel free to be creative.

Comment: this site is not a brainstorming forum ... it is a question and answer site that requires a focused question that does not have multiple answers ... `Are you aware ..?` is a question that asks about people's knowledge ... it does not ask about the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: How big is a region? Who are “people”? Anyone? A specific population? Can you extrapolate from a subset of the population (e.g. users of a specific app)?

Comment: how can the phone traffic data be accurate? ... 
 lot of people carry more than one phone .... have you considered OpenCV?

Comment: @jsotola my guess is that OP tries to do something close to the change in mobility graphs that were produced towards the beginning of the Covid crisis to measure the impact of the restrictions, so more like home-to-work commute over distances measured in km or more rather than within a room or building. But I may be wrong, hence the questions above.

Comment: @jcaron With people I mean generic people in a given area for example a 250x250 m cell over a given region (something like a choropleth map). And yes, extrapolating data from a subset would be ok.

Comment: @jsotola People with 2 cellphones is no problem since it is not the norm.

Comment: @jcaron removed the unit by mistake. just updated it? btw I don't think mm is an educated guess...

Comment: @FedericoGentile And what’s the size of the total region?

Comment: @jcaron the size of a capital city like Vienna

Comment: And what are you looking for exactly? How many people are in what area at a given point in time? How many people move from area X to area Y? Something else?

Comment: Google have a tremendous amount of data on where people are, which they use for the popular times for places in Google Maps. There is however apparently no API for that (yet?). [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60652129/using-google-api-to-tell-how-busy-a-place-is) have a few pointers to alternatives which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awesome open source project for inspiration https://github.com/opendatacam/opendatacam